# how to add the same folder permissions to another user in active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We are moving from one domain to another and it seems to take a lot of time to add permissions to special folders on shared folders to new users.
(We use AD-migrate to transfer the users.)
Is there any way to transfer all folder permissions from the user in the old domain to the new user in the new domain using powershell or anything else?

Comment: Do you mean permissions assigned to user at a folder level and not assigned via group memberships? The ladder is easy the former is not and also a poor file security choice for this and other reasons.

Comment: This is what the SID history is for.  But you should ask this question on Server Fault.

Comment: most of the folders are used by a group of users (a group was easy to transfer), but it's common that users have their private folders (by private I mean 1, 2 or 3 people from different groups can read and/or write from it) in root subfolders or even subfolders on the 3rd or 4th forrest level. I know that this is a poor file system but I'm new and the admins before me messed it up.